# How can I merge data with the same name within the same data set (perhaps with stringr)?

Tags: r

I'm working with the data set babynames, and I'm trying to find which names were the most popular, but the issue I'm having is that the same names appear more than once (because it's top names by year), so I want to find out how to merge the names that are the same into one so I don't run into this issue.

This is what I'm working with at the moment (to not screw up the bigger data set).

```
> baby.sub
# A tibble: 10 x 5
    year sex   name        n   prop
   <dbl> <chr> <chr>   <int>  <dbl>
 1  1947 F     Linda   99686 0.0548
 2  1948 F     Linda   96209 0.0552
 3  1947 M     James   94756 0.0510
 4  1957 M     Michael 92695 0.0424
 5  1947 M     Robert  91642 0.0493
 6  1949 F     Linda   91016 0.0518
 7  1956 M     Michael 90620 0.0423
 8  1958 M     Michael 90520 0.0420
 9  1948 M     James   88588 0.0497
10  1954 M     Michael 88514 0.0428
```

I've tried matching the same names with this:

```
baby.sub %>%
  str_match("[:alpha:]")
```

I got this:

```
> baby.sub %>%
+   str_match("[:alpha:]")
     [,1]
[1,] "c" 
[2,] "c" 
[3,] "c" 
[4,] "c" 
[5,] "c" 
Warning message:
In stri_match_first_regex(string, pattern, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) :
  argument is not an atomic vector; coercing
```

This stringr function clearly isn't the one I'm looking for. Does anyone have any ideas?

EDIT:

Response to a comment:
@Roman, yes I care only about names and n (the total amount of babies named that name), regardless of the year or gender.
This is what I'm trying to get from the code

```
> baby.sub
# A tibble: 10 x 5
    name       n  
    <chr>   <int> 
 1  Michael 362349
 2  Linda    286911
 3  James  183344
 4  Robert   91642
 5  James   88588
```

EDIT_2:
Solved! Thanks!

```
baby.sub <- babynames %>%
  arrange(-n) %>%
  head(10)

baby.sub %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarize(total.count = sum(n)) %>%
  arrange(-total.count)

name    total.count
  <chr>         <int>
1 Michael      362349
2 Linda        286911
3 James        183344
4 Robert        91642
```

Comment: What is the expected result in above case, @PedroGuizar?

Comment: If you care **only** about names and not about the other data you can try `unique(baby.sub$name)`. You are, however, trying to find out which names are most popular. In which year? For which gender? _Overall_? If yes, what does "overall" mean for you?

Comment: Are ``n`` and ``prop`` required in your output? If not using ``unique`` like Roman said would return you all the different names once. You could also get a count if you want.

Comment: I responded for my desired outcome in an edit above. I'll try unique and group_by

Comment: @PedroGuizar Do you want to sum all the ``n`` for each name since the ``n`` is different each years?

Comment: @Gainz Yeah, exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use group_by and summarize to sum all counts per name as following:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(babynames)

babynames %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  summarise(
  total_count = sum(n)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I like to use the `data.table` package for such things.

sample data :

```
data <- data.table(name = c("Linda", "Linda", "James", "Michael", "James"),
                   n = c(313, 310, 301, 56, 530),
                   year = c(2012,2011, 2012, 2013, 2011))
```

code :

```
       data[, .(reps = .N, total.count = sum(n)), by = .(name)]

Output :
      name  reps total.count
1:   Linda     2 623
2:   James     2 831
3: Michael     1  56
```

This is maybe not useful to you but I like that it also gives the number of time each names returns.

Answer (score 0):

I think I do not completely understand your issues, please consider improving the question.
Yet here is what I believe you are trying to achieve:

```
DataSummary <- baby.sub %>% 
                   group_by(name) %>% 
                   summarise(Total = sum(n)) %>%  #add na.rm = T if you have NULL values
                   arrange(desc(Total))  #So you get the data in order
```

If you want the result by year then:

```
 DataSummary <- baby.sub %>% 
                   group_by(name, year) %>% 
                   summarise(Total = sum(n))
```